# What is the best book(s) giving an unbiased guide to Biblical interpretation for beginners?

Tags: historical-criticism

I'm looking for a guide to interpreting the Bible as it was meant to be interpreted by its original audience, and perhaps something that details how the Bible came to be what it is today.

Although answers to the nature of this request may be subjective, I'm essentially looking for a book/guide that will help me to look at Christianity as objectively as possible.

Comment: Even a request for an unbiased guide to the Bible is open to interpretation. Most Bible commentaries have some preconceptions, such as that Christian interpretation is superior to Jewish interpretation, or even that the Bible is always - or nearly always - literally true. Do you mean without a denominational bias, or at the other extreme one that critically identifies and accepts inconsistencies that could undermine some of the message in the Bible? I think your request may be too broad for this site.

Comment: Yeah, there are always preconceptions involved - when it comes to something as crucial as the life, death and resurrection of Jesus, there are no unbiased perspectives. Everybody has a bias, whether it's to defend Jesus and the Christian perspective, or to defend themselves and their non-Christian perspective. The implications are too strong to approach without any bias - a bit like if I asked you for an unbiased perspective on your parents. For what it's worth, the original audience were Christians (of some form), so a critical Christian approach is probably closest to what you're after.

Comment: Thanks guys for the responses. @Dick Harfield Yeah I suspected my request may have been a bit broad, but no matter, jackweinbender provided me with the information I wanted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the historical and linguistic context of the Hebrew Bible (Old Testament) and Christian New Testament are significantly different, each testament (for lack of a better term) is treated—at least in the modern academy—as a separate field. While the divide is less drastic than that sounds, you're probably better off selecting a resource of one or the other (or, one for each), rather than look for something that tries to cover both testaments. If I'm reading your question correctly, you'll likely be most interested in what is commonly referred to as a "critical" introduction. That doesn't mean "critical" in a bad way; it just means that the introduction will implement some kind of critical lens (such as "historical criticism," "literary criticism," etc.) A critical intro will also tend to be "non-confessional," meaning, it will primarily be interested in the texts as products of humans, rather than as the "Word of God." Most good intros won't be *antagonistic* or *anti*-confessional, they just generally aren't concerned with teaching the theology of the text prescriptively.

For the Hebrew Bible, there are a number of good, current, critical introductions. The ones I'm most familiar with are John Collins' [Introduction to the Hebrew Bible](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1451469233) and Michael Coogan's intro [The Old Testament: A Historical and Literary Introduction to the Hebrew Scriptures](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0199946612). Both of them will give you a thorough, middle of the road, non-confessional intros. One often overlooked (and now, a bit dated) intro that I have a soft spot for is Brevard Childs' [Introduction to the Old Testament as Scripture](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0800698339). While Childs' "Canonical" approach to the Bible is not widely appreciated, he actually gives some rather nice critical information before moving to the "Canonical" stuff. I'll probably be in the minority there.

For the New Testament, [Bart Ehrman's intro](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/019020382X) is widely used and is pretty good (from my perspective). I know many confessional folks are averse to using it because of his sometimes antagonistic tone (in other works). He's a good scholar either way. I'd also recommend Luke Timothy Johnson's [The Writings of the New Testament](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0800663616) for a somewhat more sympathetic, but still critical approach. I'll also add the now dated intros by Bruce Metzger (short) [The New Testament: Its Background Growth and Content](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1426772491) and, for a more robust, historical intro, Helmut Koester's two volume [Introduction to the New Testament](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3110146924) (long).